# Creating a Legal Notice upon login in xubuntu 12.10

Tags: login, xubuntu, legal

How to Create a Legal Notice upon login in Xubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would first need to create some method to show the notice. The most straightforward way to do this would be to create a simple html page and display it to the user using `firefox file:///home/user/legal_notice.html` (from a terminal).

If that works you can proceed to add it as a 'Startup application' using the following method: http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.nl/2011/12/add-application-to-xfcexubuntu-session.html

Furthermore you need to be absolutely sure that your legal notice does not conflict with Ubuntu's software licenses (such as, but not limited to GPLv2).

Comment: Whoa!! Thanks I don't really want to set it's for a term paper and I have to set a HIPPA warning. I have it on a virtual drive now trying to get familiar with it.

Comment: I wish you good luck ;)

Comment: If all you want is a few sentences of text, `firefox` is probably overkill - consider `xmessage "Don't do bad stuff."`.